# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE_TABELLOGIN"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-intent

I have an ERROR OF :

```
while compiling: CREATE_TABELLOGIN(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERNAME text,PASSWORD text)
```

DATABASES CLASS:

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {   
  static final String DATABASE_NAME="login.db";   
  static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;   
  public static final int NAME_COLUMN=1;   
  static final String DATABASE_CREATE= "CREATE_TABEL" + "LOGIN" +
  "(" + "ID" + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);";
```

Comment: read carefuly you error it's clearly display that your collume name and colume type are mixed as single string.

Comment: solution for this.. @PankajAndroid
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABEL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABEL LOGIN ( ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You forgot to give a space before `"INTEGER` and remove the `_` (underscore) between `CREATE_TABLE`

Add a space like below,

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE= "CREATE TABLE" + "LOGIN" +
"(" + "ID" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
      "USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);";
```

Comment: CREATE_TABEL is not valid

Comment: @kalyanpvs yes, plus mine analysis is also correct.

Comment: i am not downvoter..though answer is correct so +1 from my side

Comment: `TABLE` not `TABEL`; need space between `TABLE` and `LOGIN`; the last paragraph is misleading as uninstalling is not necessary because the database wasn't created in the first place (an exception was thrown from `onCreate()`)

Comment: @laalto thanks for typo correction. But I am positive at my analysis that there should be a space between "ID" and "INTEGER..."

Comment: @Kedarnath  now ts giving the error  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABEL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABEL LOGIN ( ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);

Comment: @Bushra, Its typo, rename it to TABLE. TABEL is wrong spelling.

Answer (score 6):

That's not valid SQL.

You probably meant `CREATE TABLE LOGIN` not `CREATE_TABELLOGIN` and `ID INTEGER` not `IDINTEGER`.

Comment: This answer has all the syntax issues solved and nothing else to confuse the OP (unlike the other answers). And it was the first.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using wrong syntax for creating a table. There's no such thing as CREATE_TABELLOGIN

Refer to this [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_table.htm) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Your DATABASES CLASS:

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {   
  static final String DATABASE_NAME="login.db";   
  static final String DATATABLE_NAME ="LOGIN";   
  static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;   
  public static final int NAME_COLUMN=1;   
  static final String DATABASE_CREATE= "CREATE TABLE " + DATATABLE_NAME +
  " (" + "ID" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT);";
```

This is your correct answer check and run it.

Comment: Why did you change the table name to `login.db`?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABEL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABEL LOGIN ( ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);

Comment: Its not **TABEL** it is **TABLE**

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some issue with spacing in query.

static final String DATABASE_CREATE= "CREATE TABEL " + " LOGIN " +
"(" + " ID " + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + " USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);";

Try to print the query.

It was

```
 CREATE TABEL LOGIN(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);
```

Now it is

```
 CREATE TABEL  LOGIN ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {
static final String DATABASE_NAME="login.db";static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN=1;
 static final String DATABASE_CREATE= "CREATE TABLE " + "LOGIN" +
"(" + "ID" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + " USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);";
```

you need to add space between words and you spell **TABLE** is wrong.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABEL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABEL LOGIN ( ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME text,PASSWORD text);